# Setting InputSlot in NSPrintInfo

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing, osx-lion

Maybe I'm missing something simple and my Google-Fu is failing, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the `@"InputSlot"` key for an `NSPrintInfo` object. I can get a list for my printer (a Dymo Labelwriter 450 Twin Turbo) with:

```
NSArray * printerInputSlots = [printer stringListForKey: @"InputSlot" inTable:@"PPD"];
for (NSString* slot in printerInputSlots){
    NSLog (@"%@", slot);
}
```

and it logs: 'Auto' 'Left' 'Right', but I can't find anywhere to set which one I want to use in the `NSPrintInfo`.  I tried:

```
[[myPrintInfo dictionary] setObject:@"Left" forKey:@"InputSlot"];
```

but that didn't work.  `NSPrintPaperFeed` is deprecated, and as far as I can tell print job attributes doesn't have a key to work with feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after more searching and reading through the apple docs (again and again) i found that:

```
[[myPrintInfo printSettings] setObject@"Left" forKey:@"InputSlot"];
```

did the trick.